# Is it possible to add padding between ListView items?

Tags: android

Is it possible to add an extra space between items in a ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can write your own XML resource for a list item and specify padding you need there.

Also you can try to use [setDivider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or [setDividerHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight%28int%29) methods

Answer (score 0):

You can add some extra space by adding a bottom margin to your listview layout. Add the layout_marginBottom attribute in the XML layout file you're inflating.

Eg:

android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"